# Inverse Matrix=echolon form of $(M|E_n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it, that if i want to calculate the inverse of a matrix, the echelon form of $(M|E_n)$ will give it to me?

For example:

$\{\{1,-2,0,1,0,0\},\{0,2,1,0,1,0\},\{-1,1,2,0,0,1\}\}$ in echelon form will give the inverse of $\{\{1,-2,0\},\{0,2,1\},\{-1,1,2\}\}$

And why does a "broken" echelon form of the first imply that the matrix is not invertible?

Comment: Hint: This is essentially the same as the $AX=I$, where $X$ needs to be determined (and is obviously equal to $A^{-1}$, if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row-reduction is equivalent to multiplying $M$ on the left by a series of invertible *elementary matrices* $A_1, \dots, A_k$. If $M$ is a nonsingular square matrix, its rref is $E_n$, so we have $A_k\cdots A_1M=E_n$. On the right side of the augmented matrix we have after row-reduction $A_k\cdots A_1E_n$ since the same operations were applied to both sides. Multiplying this by $M$ we get $$A_k\cdots A_1E_nM=A_k\cdots A_1M=E_n,$$ therefore $$A_k\cdots A_1E_n=M^{-1}.$$

As for your second question, note that an elementary row operation either leaves the determinant unchanged or multiplies it by some non-zero value. If the rref has a zero row, then its determinant is obviously zero, hence so is the determinant of the original matrix.